# How to use ajax inside javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have below js function, I need to call /print2 function without clicking any buttons. I tried to write ajax to that. By the way, I am newer in ajax and js.

Where is the problem ı could not see ?

Thank you...

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
     function plot() {


    $.ajax({
        url: '/print2',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('get info');

            $('#description').html(data['description']);
        }
    });


}

   plot()
</script>
```

It says

(index):30 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at plot ((index):30) at (index):38

Where is the problem ?

## Edit

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //your code here
});
```

I wrapped my function with this code. As it stated here [JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

However, I  it is not solve my problem.

Comment: Are you including jQuery...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: how can I do that ?

Comment: I did it  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined and             add this $(document).ready(function () {
  //your code here
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you do not have jQuery. To get jQuery you include the following script at the end of the body tag in your HTML.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

make sure it is before this closing tag below.

```
</body>
```

Comment: @ozer jQuery is a JavaScript library - think of it as an "extension" to JavaScript. All references to `$` in your code are trying to reference jQuery functions, but without including jQuery, you can't use jQuery functions.

Comment: @ozer Ajax is built into jQuery. You can not use one without the other. This script tag tells the browser to load jQuery into your page. Without it, you will not be able to use any jQuery functionality. If the answer fixed our issue please select it as closed to let others know that the issue has been solved.

Comment: @thatguy *"You can not use one without the other. "* - this is incorrect. You can certainly use jQuery without AJAX, and you can certainly use AJAX without jQuery.

Comment: @TylerRoper  you can use 'XMLHttpRequest' without jQuery which is technically AJAX, but the '$.ajax' syntax is a part of the jQuery framework which you will need to use it. That is an argument of semantics. While technically the same, but still different.

Comment: "You can't use one without the other" implies that you can't use jQuery without AJAX, which doesn't really make sense. It seems you're specifically referring to `$.ajax`, in which case that's correct, you cannot use this specific method without jQuery. I think the issue may lie in semantics, but the end result is a comment that is misleading/wrong. AJAX is completely supported without jQuery (`fetch`, `XMLHttpRequest`, etc) - however *the jQuery `$.ajax` method, specifically* is not.

Comment: @TylerRoper True, and I can see your issue with the comment and understand where you are coming from. My comment was more directed towards the $.ajax syntax the OP is using while also not trying to confuse or overwhelm a newer developer. Keeping it simple in the beginning is key to learning. Deep dives into the technologies and semantical differences will only confuse and deter someone who is just learning.

Comment: @thatguy Agreed. However, and this is important, please note that everything on StackOverflow, from questions, to comments, to answers, are supposed to work towards building a repository of useful Q&A-style knowledge **for everyone**. Any time you answer or comment on a question, consider that the content is for an audience of thousands and thousands, as opposed to solely the one person who asked the question :)

Comment: @TylerRoper makes sense. I will be sure to be more explicit in the future.